# Flutter ReceiverPort don't listen

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-isolates, flutter-downloader

I'm using the **flutter_downloader** package to download files with my app.
The progress notification is working nicely. but my **ReceivePort** is not listening to the progress.

```
  final ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();

     @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

     IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        port.sendPort, 'downloader_sendport');

     port.listen((dynamic data) async {
       log('data: $data');  // don't work

     });
     FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);
   }


@pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void downloadCallback(
      String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
    log("downloadCallback => $id, $status, $progress"); // works

    final SendPort? send =
        IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_sendport');

   

    send?.send([id, status, progress]);
  }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SendPort` needs to receive a primitive object (`int`), not a `DownloadTaskStatus` object:

Solution: Change `status` to primitive `status.value` when calling `send(...)`:

```
send?.send([id, status.value, progress]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `status` to primitive `status.value` in send method.